# Solving a complicated time-dependent function

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, functions, physics, piecewise

I want to solve the following time-dependent system of equations:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
q = (((1602176634)/10^9))*10^(-19);
k = (((1380649)/10^6))*10^(-23);
\[Eta] = 3/2;
Td = 20 + (5463/20);
R1 = 10;
Vi = Piecewise[{{u*Sin[\[Omega]*t], 
     0 <= t <= ((2*Pi)/\[Omega])/2}, {0, t > ((2*Pi)/\[Omega])/2}}];
u = 230*Sqrt[2];
\[Omega] = 2*Pi*50;
Is = 5*10^(-9);
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == Is*(Exp[(q*(Vi - V1))/(\[Eta]*k*Td)] - 1), 
   I1 == Is*(Exp[(q*(V1 - V2))/(\[Eta]*k*Td)] - 1), I1 == V2/R1}, {I1,
    V1, V2}]]
```

But it spits out nothing, just the simplified version of the input. Is there a way to solve for the unknowns $I_1$, $V_1$ and $V_2$?

Comment: `Vi` is a function of `t `but I can not see any `t `in your equations.

Comment: @DanielHuber because the input is a function of time the outputs are also, do I need to specify that? And if so, how do I do that?

Comment: If `Vi` is to be treated like a constant in your equation, then replace it by a symbol without value ( e.g. `Vi0`), then solve the equations and replace  `Vi0`in the solution by `Vi`

Comment: @DanielHuber Does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get no result because `Vi` is a function.

If you replace `Vi`, say `Vi0` by a constant you will get a solution that is not unique. But if you restrict the solutions to `Reals` you will get a unique results.

Here is the procedure:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
q = (((1602176634)/10^9))*10^(-19);
k = (((1380649)/10^6))*10^(-23);
\[Eta] = 3/2;
Td = 20 + (5463/20);
R1 = 10;
Vi = Piecewise[{{u*Sin[\[Omega]*t], 
     0 <= t <= ((2*Pi)/\[Omega])/2}, {0, t > ((2*Pi)/\[Omega])/2}}];
u = 230*Sqrt[2];
\[Omega] = 2*Pi*50;
Is = 5*10^(-9);
FullSimplify[
  sol = Solve[{I1 == Is*(Exp[(q*(Vi0 - V1))/(\[Eta]*k*Td)] - 1), 
      I1 == Is*(Exp[(q*(V1 - V2))/(\[Eta]*k*Td)] - 1), 
      I1 == V2/R1}, {I1, V1, V2}, Reals][[1]]];
funs[t_] = {I1, V1, V2} /. sol /. Vi0 -> Vi // Simplify;
```

You can now plot the solutions:

```
Plot[funs[t], {t, 0, .01}]
```

[image]

You only see 2 functions, because the 2. and 3. component of `funs` are nearly the identical. However, we may plot the difference:

Plot[funs[x][[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFyy3.png)] - funs[x][[3]], {x, 0, .01}]

[image]